# Differentiating an endomorphism

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,\rho)$ be a symplectic $2$-dimensional manifold, and let $J$ be a compatible complex structure on $M$, i.e. the symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor
$$g(*,*) = \rho(*,J*)$$
is a Riemannian metric. Denote by $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection. Now let $V\in\Gamma(TM)$ be a vector field (with some further assumptions which are probably not needed). I would like to compute
$$\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\left((d\varphi_V^{-t})_{\varphi_V^t(m)}J(\varphi_V^t(m))(d\varphi_V^t)_m\right),$$
where the map in the brackets is a map $T_mM\to T_mM$. Here $\varphi_V^t$ denotes the flow of $V$. If my computations are correct, I get the expression
$$-\nabla_{J*}V + (\nabla_VJ)(*) + J(\nabla_*V)\tag{1},$$
which is again an endomorphism of $TM$. I would like to further simplify this expression. This would be easy if we had
$$\nabla_{J*}V = J(\nabla_*V),$$
but I'm afraid that this is not true (at least without some more assumptions/structure). The only results I have about relations between $\nabla$ and $J$ are
$$J(\nabla_*J) = (\nabla_*J)J\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\nabla_{J*}J = -J(\nabla_*J)$$
(see e.g. lemma 4.1.14 in [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198504519)), but I haven't been able to get anywhere using them.

My questions are:

1. Is my computation $(1)$ correct?
2. Is it possible to further simplify the expression $(1)$?

If you think that further assumptions are needed to solve the problem, please let me know.

Comment: I don't know all that much geometry myself, so I can't directly answer your questions, but that derivative looks a lot like the definition of the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_V W$ of one vector field along another, which turns out to be equal to the Lie bracket $[V, W]$. Maybe this can help confirm your computations?

Comment: @AlexG. Yes, it is *exactly* the Lie derivative of a section of the endomorphism bundle (as the expression we're differentiating is $(\varphi_V^t)^*J$). I'm not sure I have tried to work on it like that though, so i will try :) Thanks for the input.

Comment: @AlexG. I tried, by writing $J = a^\mu\otimes b_\mu$ and using distributivity of the Lie derivative over the tensor and Cartan's magic formula, but I don't get a nice expression. But maybe I'm just going about it in the wrong way...